# See which Users have Logged onto Wifi?

Tags: raspbian, networking, pi-3

I currently have my Raspberry Pi 3 configured so that it provides a wireless access point. I mostly followed [this](https://frillip.com/using-your-raspberry-pi-3-as-a-wifi-access-point-with-hostapd/) tutorial, although I changed a few things. I would like to be able to see every device that has been on my access point. Is there a way to do this? If possible I want to be able to see the date on which the devices first came onto my wifi also. I want this so that I can have a count of how many different devices have been on my wifi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following command will show you devices currently connected to your hotspot:

```
arp-scan --interface=wlan0 --localnet
```

*If your hotspot is not on wlan0 adjust the interface option appropriately*

Of course you'll have to do more work on formatting the output of it. It was the above command that helped me in the project based on the same tutorial that you followed.

Comment: I would like to keep track of how many different users have been on the wifi ever...would I run this command every few minutes or is there a way to make it so that every time a new user logs in it adds him/her to the list?

Comment: This command is what let's you see new users in the first place hence polling (running this command every few seconds) is unavoidable. Also as far as tracking users that have been on your hotspot goes you're going to want use a database. A nice and simple database implementation can be done in sqlite3.

Comment: Isn't there something that would add each "new" user to a file when they logged on? Then to see how many different users had logged on you would count the number of lines in the file.

Comment: You'd want to write your own script to keep track of such things. Python is great for that stuff and by the use of `peewee` module you can interface to an sqlite3 database easily.